# Need to get max value controlcode from datatable of type string

Tags: c#

i attached the image of datatable values ,in that list i am getting max value 1010080009,but i need to get 10100800019,

```
if(dtItemsplitfiltrExist.rows.count>0)
{
    long  l1 = Convert.ToInt32(dtItemsplitfiltrExist.Compute("Max(ControlCode)", string.Empty));


    l1 = long.Parse("0" + Convert.ToString(dtItemsplitfiltrExist.Compute("max(ControlCode)", string.Empty)));
}
```

both way i tried i m getting  1010080009[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpxdI.jpg)

Comment: Try using LINQ: `l1 = Convert.ToInt32(dtItemsplitfiltrExist.AsEnumerable().Max(row => row["ControlCode"]));`

Answer (score 0):

```
var max = dtItemsplitfiltrExist
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Where(x => x["ControlCode"] != DBNull.Value)
  .Max(x => x.Field<long>("ControlCode"));
```

this will help you,

you can cast this to int if you want.